# Ai oboete imasu ka, what does "imasu" add here?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, conjugations, aspect

"Ai oboete imasu ka" is translated as "Do you remember love?", now Ai is love, oboete is remember and ka is the question marker, why do you need to add "imasu" to this phrase?

Comment: I love the Eiríkr Útlendi's answer, but this question is also related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010

Comment: Thank you for the link, @naruto!  That answer doesn't directly address this question, but it is more comprehensive, and discusses more verb types.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### A note on translation

Expressing the same ideas in different languages inevitably results in all kinds of things that don't fit very well, if we try to look only at the individual words used in those expressions.  This makes things quite difficult for the beginning learner, since we don't yet have a bigger-picture understanding of how a given language works.

So when we analyze how a given expression works in Language A, and we try to explain how that matches up with the expression in Language B that has roughly the same meaning, the explanation sometimes has to get pretty deep and nitty-gritty.  :)

#### Background on the verb

The main verb here is the *oboete* (dictionary form: 覚える *oboeru*).  The verb *oboeru* is often translated as *"remember"*, but the **aspect** of the Japanese verb is a bit different.

**Aspect** is a tricky concept, and I won't get into it here -- read [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) for the details.

In a simplified nutshell, the English verb *"remember"* does not express any change in state: the person doesn't necessarily change at all, comparing them before they remember something, and after.

The Japanese verb *oboeru*, however, **does** include a change in state, and this is closer to the English verb *"memorize"*.  In Japanese, you can say 漢字{かんじ}を**覚える{おぼえる}** to express the concept, *"I **memorize** the kanji."*  The change in state here is that the person doesn't have the kanji in their head before they *oboeru*, and they **do** have the kanji in their head after they *oboeru*.  A better translation thus might be *"put something in mind"*.

#### Main question: what does the *imasu* do here?

The Japanese verb *imasu* (dictionary form: いる *iru*) is often translated as *"am, is, be"*.  This is usually a good fit -- 店{みせ}に行{い}きます, *"I go to the store"*, vs. 店{みせ}に行{い}って**います**, *"I **am** go​**ing** to the store"*.  In most cases, *imasu* is used as an auxiliary (additional) verb to indicate the present progressive -- something **is** happen​**ing**.

However, verbs that indicate a change of state -- and this gets back to that tricky idea of **aspect** -- can take *imasu* to mean either 1) that the verb **is** happen​**ing**, or 2) that the change indicated by the verb **has** happen​**ed** and the new state **is**.

By way of example, 切{き}れる (*kireru*) is another of those verbs that indicates a change in state, and it basically means *"to become cut"*.  So 紙{かみ}が切{き}れる means *"the paper becomes cut"* → *"the paper changes state from whole, to cut into pieces"*.  紙{かみ}が切{き}れて**いる** could mean *"the paper **is** becom​**ing** cut"*, or it could mean *"the paper **has been** cut"* → *"the paper **is** now in a state of having been cut"*.  Context makes it clear which interpretation is more appropriate.

Looking back to the core verb *oboeru*, when we add *imasu*, we could mean that the person **is** memoriz​**ing** something -- this is a valid translation, but it depends on the context.  The context in your example sentence suggests that the second interpretation makes more sense -- the person isn't in the process of memorizing love, or of putting love into their minds, but instead **has** put love in mind, i.e. they **have** it in their head → they **remember** it.

Comment: 1. Don't movement verbs function like change-in-state verbs in ている form? ([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3140/30454)) Namely, isn't the primary interpretation of 店に行っています "(someone) has gone to the store"? I thought the interpretation mentioned in your answer--the present progressive--was possible but not the default and would likely call for a temporal adverbial. ([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66145/30454)) 2. since 切れる is a change-in-state verb, doesn't ている show the continuation of a state. So isn't "becoming cut" the unlikely understanding?(source: also Derek)