# Kao wa oboeta: remembered or memorized?

Tags: tense

Does this mean that the person remembered the person's face from seeing it somewhere before this moment or that he had his face  memorized just now? There isn't context to it so I'm not sure. Can it go both ways?

Comment: Somewhat related post [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38768/ai-oboete-imasu-ka-what-does-imasu-add-here/38773#38773).

Answer (score 3):

覚える (oboeru) means *to memorize*, 思い出す(omoidasu) means *to recall*. So the sentence means "I memorized (at  least) his face (just now)."

By the way, how come a sentence like this doesn't have a context? Is this a song title or such?